# how to print data between <p> and </p> beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am writing a script to scrape the highs and lows of weather on a weather site, and I have gotten it to print what I need, but with all of the Beautifulsoup tags.

This is my current script:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

website = "http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=39.90489741058809&lon=-82.7617367885212&site=all&smap=1#.VPyDd4F4qAQ"

r1 = urllib2.urlopen(website)
mydata = r1.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(mydata)
s = soup.prettify()
x = soup.find_all("p", attrs={"class": "point-forecast-icons-low"})
y = soup.find_all("p", attrs={"class": "point-forecast-icons-high"})

print x
print y
```

It gives me this:

```
[<p class="point-forecast-icons-low">Low: 40 °F</p>, <p class="point-forecast-icons-low">Low: 48 °F</p>, <p class="point-forecast-icons-low">Low: 26 °F</p>, <p class="point-forecast-icons-low">Low: 31 °F</p>, <p class="point-forecast-icons-low">Low: 32 °F</p>]
[<p class="point-forecast-icons-high">High: 67 °F</p>, <p class="point-forecast-icons-high">High: 53 °F</p>, <p class="point-forecast-icons-high">High: 44 °F</p>, <p class="point-forecast-icons-high">High: 47 °F</p>]
```

But I just want the parts that say "High: ##" and "Low: ##."

How do I do that??

Comment: Your code doesn't work and cannot work; the result of `find_all()` does **not** have a `.text` attribute; you'd get an attribute error.

Answer (score 1):

You have lists of elements. Use the `Element.text` attribute *on each separate element*:

```
lows = [low.text for low in soup.find_all("p", class_="point-forecast-icons-low")]
highs = [high.text for high in soup.find_all("p", class_="point-forecast-icons-high")]
```

This produces:

```
>>> lows = [low.text for low in soup.find_all("p", class_="point-forecast-icons-low")]
>>> highs = [high.text for high in soup.find_all("p", class_="point-forecast-icons-high")]
>>> lows
[u'Low: 40 \xb0F', u'Low: 48 \xb0F', u'Low: 26 \xb0F', u'Low: 31 \xb0F', u'Low: 32 \xb0F']
>>> highs
[u'High: 67 \xb0F', u'High: 53 \xb0F', u'High: 44 \xb0F', u'High: 47 \xb0F']
```

The `°` in `°F` is not an ASCII printable character so it is represented as the `\xb0` escape sequence when shown in a list. You can print the individual values:

```
>>> print highs[0]
High: 67 °F
```

Comment: @Twozie you could loop over the lists, or use `str.join()` or any other formatting